# Plotting orbit diagram of this map (discrete dynamical system)

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab

I want to plot the orbit diagram of the system $x_{n+1}=x_n e^{r(1-x)(\frac{x}{0.2}-1)}$ for $0.3 <r<1$ and 8000 time steps which the last 300 are ploted with initial conditions $0.08,\; 0.44,\; 0.73,\; 0.76$ and $0.99$ in matlab. I wrote the following code but it doesn't work.

```
close all
clear all
avalues=0.3:0.01:0.9;
N=8000;
a=avalues;
x=0.08;
X=zeros(N,length(a));
for n=1:0.3*N
    x=x.*exp(a.*(1-x).*((x/0.2)-1));
    X(n,:)=x;
end

figure (9), hold on 
for n=.3*N:N
    x=x.*exp(a.*(1-x).*((x/0.2)-1));
    X(n,:)=x;
    plot(a,x,'.','MarkerSize',0.01)
    axis([0.3 0.9 0 1.4])
end
hold off
```

I was wondering if someone could help me about my problem.

Comment: Dear @AVK , I'd like to plot the orbit diagram of the coupled system $F(x,_n y_n )=((1-d)f(x_n )+df(y_n ),df(x_n )+(1-d)f(y_n))$ for $d=0.03$ in which $x_n$ and $y_n$ are two local systems with the same dynamics as $f(x_n)=x_n e^{r(1-x)(\frac{x}{0.2}-1)}$.

Comment: @AVK I was wondering if you could help me about my problem. Initial conditions are $(0.44,0.14),(0.73,0.11),(0.76,0.73)$ and $(0.99,0.17)$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. There are dots at the bottom of the graph, which are the orbit diagram:
[image: x_0 = 0.08]

If $x_0 = 0.08$, then all trajectories tend to zero, which is shown in the figure above. If you take $x_0 = 0.78$, you can see a completely different picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.